# How to force a page break in HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp?

Tags: html-renderer

I'm using "HTML Renderer for PDF using PDFsharp" `HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp` (version 1.5.1-beta1). I'm trying to force a page break. But I can't get this to work. What I have now in my html is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
      xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Test</title>

    <style>
    div { page-break-inside: auto; }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="margin:0; padding:0;" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
    <div>Page1</div>
    <div>Page2</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Both `div` stay on the same page when I convert this html to PDF.

```
string contents = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\temp\test.html");
PdfDocument pdf = PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf(contents, PageSize.A4);
pdf.Save(@"C:\temp\pdfsharp.pdf");
```

How can I force the second div to a new page?

Comment: try to use page-break-before:true on div2

Answer (score 0):

The only known solution to force page breaks is to split the html into parts, and generate a page for each html part. Solution from Grasher134 on GitHub: https://github.com/ArthurHub/HTML-Renderer/issues/49#issuecomment-251351431